# Enable button on any form change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button thats currently disabled. Once any changes have been made to the inputs in the form. I'd like to enable it....

```
$('input[class="input-text"]').on('change', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#checkout').removeAttr('disabled');
});

 ...
<button type="submit" className="btn" id="checkout" disabled>Checkout</button>
```

This doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong? (using .jsx syntax)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Attach `input` and `change` both event on a `<form>`.

Check the following example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#form').on('input change', function() {
    $('#checkout').attr('disabled', false);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  Text:
  <input type="text" class="input-text" />
  <br>Radio:
  <input type="radio">
  <br>Checkbox:
  <input type="checkbox">
  <br>Select:
  <select name="" id="">
    <br>
    <option value="">1</option>
    <option value="">2</option>
    <option value="">3</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" className="btn" id="checkout" disabled>Checkout</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using jQuery, just use the [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function (and class selector for more efficient lookup):

```
$('input.input-text').on('change', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#checkout').attr('disabled', false);
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rb9hw2ut/)

Please note: the `change` event is only triggered when the `.input-text` is blurred. You may wish to consider using `onkeyup` (or similar).

Comment: Hmm while I think keyup makes sense. It would still be enabled if the user decided to remove anything that they added.

Comment: Yep, that's true. Well, the code above will achieve what you need.

Comment: also function(e) will not work in jsx without an expression name

Comment: Then it's probably worthwhile to mention in the question that you're using a preprocessor. Either way, the above code achieves what you're looking for, even if the demonstrated syntax is slightly different (or needs modifying to exactly suit your reqs).